# Angular ui-router. Child state parameter based on parent state parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router with Angular 1.6. The root state is the site language (/en, /nl, /de).

Most child states are the same for all languages. However, for some states the names of the child states are translated:

```
/en/english-state/common-state
/nl/dutch-state/common-state
/de/german-state/common-state
```

How can I make sure the middle state always matches the lang parameter (en/nl/de) in the parent state? I'd like to use ui-sref without providing the middle state; this should be filled automatically based on the language. When the middle state doesn't match the language in the parent state it should be changed automatically to match the language in the parent state.

I can't find an intuitive solution in the ui-router docs, but perhaps I'm missing something. Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I've decided to solve it like this, which I think is the cleanest way to do it:

(Note: This is a simplified version. I've replaced functions with strings , omitted dependencies and removed lines, this is not-working code, it's about the idea).

- Expose the language variable in the resolve part of the root state, something like this:

  ```
  $stateProvider.state({
      url: '/{lang:(?:en|nl|de)}',
      name: 'root',
      [ ... ]
      resolve: {
          language: function() { return $stateParams.lang }
      }
  ```
- In the child state, check if the URL matches the language:

  ```
  $stateProvider.state({
      url: '/{mySlug:(?:english-state|dutch-state|german-state|__my-state__)}',            
      name: 'root.child',
      resolve: {
          checkSlug: function () {
              $timout(function() {

                  if (notMatchesLanguage($stateParams.mySlug, language)) {
                          var params = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($stateParams));
                          params.mySlug = correctSlug;

                          $state.transitionTo($state.current.name, params, { notify: false });
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  ```
- Note the added slug in the mySlug list, __my-state_ _
- Now in every ui-sref, or $state.go we can use __my-state_ as mySlug parameter. This strange slug won't match any language and will be replaced with the matching state slug.